# Simple HTML/CSS: Place paragraph after header inline with header?

Tags: html, css, inline

CSS code:

```
h4 {
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

HTML test code:

```
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" /></title>test</title></head>
<body>
  <p>Let's try to make a header be inline with the next paragraph.</p>
  <h4>This is a header.</h4>
  <p>A header is an HTML element. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam aliquam consequat enim eget porta. Proin condimentum dui sed tortor semper, non scelerisque risus volutpat. Vivamus vel risus in purus imperdiet finibus. Phasellus placerat nunc a orci ullamcorper, non ultricies neque auctor. Integer magna lectus, vulputate laoreet auctor eu, gravida et lorem.</p>
<p>And now we have some more text.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected output:

> Let's try to make a header be inline with the next paragraph.
>
> **This is a header.** A header is an HTML element. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam aliquam consequat enim eget porta. Proin condimentum dui sed tortor semper, non scelerisque risus volutpat. Vivamus vel risus in purus imperdiet finibus. Phasellus placerat nunc a orci ullamcorper, non ultricies neque auctor. Integer magna lectus, vulputate laoreet auctor eu, gravida et lorem.
>
> And now we have some more text.

What I'm actually getting:

> Let's try to make a header be inline with the next paragraph.
>
> **This is a header.**
>
> A header is an HTML element. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam aliquam consequat enim eget porta. Proin condimentum dui sed tortor semper, non scelerisque risus volutpat. Vivamus vel risus in purus imperdiet finibus. Phasellus placerat nunc a orci ullamcorper, non ultricies neque auctor. Integer magna lectus, vulputate laoreet auctor eu, gravida et lorem.
>
> And now we have some more text.

I'm almost positive the issue is the fact that I'm starting a new paragraph right after the header. The problem is, the HTML code I'm applying styles to is not my own - it's generated by another tool which I don't have source code for, so I can't just, say, eliminate the paragraph, or add styling to the paragraph directly. Can the above be done with exactly the given HTML code and only using CSS?

---

**Edit:** The proposed solution of using `h4; h4 + p` does work - provided there are at least two paragraphs following the `<h4>` tag. The following HTML code will cause undesired results:

```
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" /?</title>test</title></head>
<body>
  <p>Let's try to make a header be inline with the next paragraph.</p>
  <h4>This is a header.</h4>
  <p>A header is an HTML element. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam aliquam consequat enim eget porta. Proin condimentum dui sed tortor semper, non scelerisque risus volutpat. Vivamus vel risus in purus imperdiet finibus. Phasellus placerat nunc a orci ullamcorper, non ultricies neque auctor. Integer magna lectus, vulputate laoreet auctor eu, gravida et lorem.</p>
  <h4>This is another header...</h4>
  <p>And now we have some more text.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Results:

> Let's try to make a header be inline with the next paragraph.
>
> **This is a header.** A header is an HTML element. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam aliquam consequat enim eget porta. Proin condimentum dui sed tortor semper, non scelerisque risus volutpat. Vivamus vel risus in purus imperdiet finibus. Phasellus placerat nunc a orci ullamcorper, non ultricies neque auctor. Integer magna lectus, vulputate laoreet auctor eu, gravida et lorem. **This is another header...** And now we have some more text.

Expected result:

> Let's try to make a header be inline with the next paragraph.
>
> **This is a header.** A header is an HTML element. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam aliquam consequat enim eget porta. Proin condimentum dui sed tortor semper, non scelerisque risus volutpat. Vivamus vel risus in purus imperdiet finibus. Phasellus placerat nunc a orci ullamcorper, non ultricies neque auctor. Integer magna lectus, vulputate laoreet auctor eu, gravida et lorem.
>
> **This is another header...** And now we have some more text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd modify @Nit's code by adding a pseudo-element before your `h4`:

```
h4,
h4 + p {
  display: inline;
}
h4:before {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   clear: left;
   margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you simply want to make the header and the paragraph following right next to it inline?

```css
h4,
h4 + p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>Let's try to make a header be inline with the next paragraph.</p>
<h4>This is a header.</h4>
<p>A header is an HTML element. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam aliquam consequat enim eget porta. Proin condimentum dui sed tortor semper, non scelerisque risus volutpat. Vivamus vel risus in purus imperdiet finibus. Phasellus
  placerat nunc a orci ullamcorper, non ultricies neque auctor. Integer magna lectus, vulputate laoreet auctor eu, gravida et lorem.</p>
<p>And now we have some more text.</p>
```

Comment: Ok, I did find one case where this doesn't work... <h4>Some header</h4> <p>Some paragraph text.</p> <h4>Another header.</h4> <p>Some more paragraph text.</p> If you have this, all four blocks show up inline as a single paragraph...